# Help with understanding this pam config's auth section

Tags: pam

I've inherited this pam config and was auditing it while also adding pam_access.

I'm trying to understand specifically the `auth` `pam_succeed_if` and `auth` `pam_localuser` lines.

```
#%PAM-1.0                                                                                 
# This file is auto-generated, but maintained in ansible.                                 
# Changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.                              
                                                                                          
auth        required      pam_env.so                                                      
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000                                  
# vvvvvv                                           
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 200 quiet       
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so 
# ^^^^^^                        
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass                                                                   
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 200 quiet_success                      
auth        sufficient    pam_sss.so forward_pass                                         
auth        required      pam_deny.so                                                     
                                                                                          
account     required      pam_access.so                                                   
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow                                       
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so                                                
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 200 quiet                               
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so                       
account     required      pam_permit.so                                                   
                                                                                          
password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok        
password    sufficient    pam_sss.so use_authtok                                          
password    required      pam_deny.so                                                     
                                                                                          
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke                                           
session     required      pam_limits.so                                                   
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so                                                 
# session     optional      pam_oddjob_mkhomedir.so umask=0077                            
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid   
session     required      pam_unix.so                                                     
session     optional      pam_sss.so
```

I've been having a hard time finding documentation on the `[...]` section, specifically what `default=1` does.  It skips the next line is my understanding?

- If our uid >= 200, then we pass OK, continue, skip pam_localuser, and check pam_unix next.
- If our uid < 200, then we fall through to pam_localuser.
- At pam_localuser, if true, we skip pam_unix (??? is that ok???)

This seems overcomplicated and I can't quite get what the point is of this section.

Can someone explain the intent?

Answer (score 0):

A positive integer to `default` skips rules, according to
`modules/pam_succeed_if/pam_succeed_if.8.xml` under the
[linux-pam](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam) project:

```
    <para>
      Given that the type matches, only loads the othermodule rule if
      the UID is over 500. Adjust the number after default to skip
      several rules.
    </para>
    <programlisting>
type [default=1 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid &gt; 500
type required othermodule.so arguments...
    </programlisting>
```

The other actions are non-strictly-positive integers, usually via a text
label such as `default=die` or `default=ignore`; these token actions are
listed in `libpam/pam_tokens.h`.

`pam_localuser` skips `pam_unix` as presumably uid < 200 are local system
accounts that do not need authentication via a password hash or the
like, these being the `auth` section rules. Usually such role accounts
will also have a `false` or `nologin` shell set.